# What is the Time Complexity of Set operation of a BitSet in java?

Tags: java, time-complexity, bit, bitset

I have a Scenario where I have to set a range of BitSet index to 1.
So if I use

```
   /*
    *Code snippet
    */
    BitSet myBitSet = new BitSet(100);
    myBitSet.set(10, 50);

    //**************************
```

What would be the time complexity for above code? will it iterate through 40 elements or some kind of bit operation will be performed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single bit it will be O(1), the complexity for setting n bits is O(N).

For the sceptics: setting n bits is O(N), because setting 10_000 bits takes about 10 times longer than setting 1_000 bits.

That said, it is more effecient to call `myBitSet.set(10,50)` than to write `for (int i=10; i<=50; i++) myBitSet.set(i);`

Comment: Yes I understood it now. Thank you for the quick response :) .

Answer (score 4):

For some reason it isn't specified in the Javadoc, but the Oracle implementation is certainly *O(1)* for get, set, flip, and clear with one parameter; *O(N)* with two parameters. 'Vector of bits' may be intended as a hint.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :) .

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses an array both set/get are O(1)

Comment: Since it iterates between `fromIndex` and `toIndex` in the case the OP is asking about it is *O(N)*.

Comment: And 'since it uses an array' is a *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 0):

The set operation will set the bits (fromIndex will be 10 and toIndex would be 49)
It will iterate through 40 elements starting from 10 to 49. And yes, the complexity will be O(1)

Comment: How can an iteration be *O(1)*?

Comment: because the amount is limited. O(40* 1) = O(1)

Comment: Furthermore with fromIndex 10 and toIndex 49 there are only 39 elements because toIndex is exclusive.